# Can I remove this laser barrier?

Tags: headlander

[image]

There's a horizontal laser across the raised platform in the middle of this room that zaps you if you walk out onto it.

You can go around it, but there is clearly access down to some other room in the middle.

I haven't seen any dogs or vacuum units about that would fit through there.

In a later stage, there was a room with lasers pointing all over the place and firing furiously seemed to deactivate them. I've tried that here but without any luck.

There does seem to be a room down there:

[image]

Is there a way through?

Answer (score 1):

You can get through to the room below by headlanding onto a body that is short enough to walk under the beam, there's a couple of bodies nearby that will do the job.